# jQuery Blur() not working with click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am trying to make a tooltip with content disappear when I click outside it, but tried solutions to different posts and none of those solutions work for me.

I think the problem is how I am triggering the tooltip, but is the only way I know, here is the code I have in my js and my html markup.

The tooltip fires well, but it doesn't work with the blur event in any way I tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function tooltover(target_item){
        $(target_item + '> a').click(function(){
            $('.tiptover_box').focus();

            var pos = $(this).position();
            var width = $(this).outerWidth();
            var boxw = $(this).next().outerWidth();
            var boxh = $(this).next().outerHeight();

            $(this).next().css('left', (pos.left - ((boxw/2)-(width/2))));
            $(this).next().css('top', (pos.top - (boxh+5)));
            $(this).next().addClass('tiptover_show');
            $(this).next().delay(5).queue(function(){
                $(this).addClass('tt-in');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        });
        $('.tiptover_box').blur( function(){
            $('.tiptover_box').removeClass('tiptover_show tt-in');
        });
    } tooltover('.tiptover');

});
```

And **HTML**

```
<div class="tiptover">
    <a>Link Test</a>
    <div class="tiptover_box" style="background-image: url(content/prod_0002.jpg);">
        <div>Description.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach would be to not focus on the div itself, but focus on the rest of the DOM.

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/540812) given by [prc322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659025/prc322) on a similar question he used the `mouseup` event on the `document` itself:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".tiptover_box");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.removeClass('tiptover_show tt-in');
    }
});
```

<sup>(edited by me for relevance)</sup>

Now your tooltip will be "closed" whenever a `mouseup` event fired on any element that is not the `.tiptover_box` or any of its descendants.

Comment: Good News, this worked just as expected. Thank you very much. I had the feeling that something was more reliable in other way than just a blur. I will be adding some minor functionalities to add and remove some css classes. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to trigger the `blur` event of a div (which is not as reliable as blurring an input field), you can do what you say you want - when anything is clicked, you hide the tooltip:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
        var tooltipContainer = $('.tiptover_box');
        var clickTarget = e.target;

        if(!tooltipContainer.is(clickTarget)
          && tooltipContainer.has(clickTarget).length === 0){
            tooltipContainer.removeClass('tiptover_show tt-in');
        }
});
```

edit: added test for container and its children, basically same as the answer from Bob.

Comment: Please explain why is it not reliable?

Comment: @Bob - divs do not fire the `onfocusout` event.

Comment: Thank you my friend, This didn't work, I tested and the tooltip didn't fired. In fact did a little extra trouble with other functionalities than the tooltip, may be a conflict with the click of bootstrap

Comment: When clicking the body and its descendants (even the tooltip itself) the class will be removed now.

Comment: Yeah, missed that, @Bob, updating my answer.